# How to Create a Customized Table in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a customized table with sub-component in react but I can't achieve it

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

const DataTableContext = React.createContext();


const Header = () => {
    return (
        <DataTableContext.Consumer {...props}>
            <thead>{props.children}</thead>
        </DataTableContext.Consumer>);
}
const Row = (props) => {
    return (
        <DataTableContext.Consumer>
            <tr>{props.children}</tr>
        </DataTableContext.Consumer>);
}
const Cell = (props) => {
    return (
        <DataTableContext.Consumer>
            <td style={{ width: props.width }}>{props.children}</td>
        </DataTableContext.Consumer>);
}
const Body = (props) => {
    return (
        <DataTableContext.Consumer>
            <tbody>{props.children}</tbody>
        </DataTableContext.Consumer>);
}

const DataTable = props => {
    return (
        <DataTableContext.Provider {...props}>
            <table className="bordered">{props.children}</table>
        </DataTableContext.Provider>
    );
}


DataTable.Header = Header;
DataTable.Row = Row;
DataTable.Cell = Cell;
DataTable.Body = Body;

export default DataTable
```

is there any way to solve my problem ?
I have also  referenced following article:
https://medium.com/maxime-heckel/react-sub-components-part-2-using-the-new-context-api-6f1c089acfe4

Comment: this code makes no sense nor you post what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to use `Context.Consumer`, take your `Cell` for example:

```
const Cell = ({ width, children }) => (
  <DataTableContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => <td style={{ width }}>{children}</td>}
  </DataTableContext.Consumer>
);
```

I suggest you to use `useContext` not `Consumer` like this:

```
const Cell = ({ width, children }) => {
  const context = useContext(DataTableContext);

  return <td style={{ width }}>{children}</td>;
};
```

And you don't need `Context` API, if you only want to custom your table without data passed.